# Build VUE3/vite project with dynamic import

Tags: vuejs3

My new VUE3 (with vite) project will be used by different clients.
So i have a subfolder with some client-specific configuration files, in main.ts im loading it like:

```
var currentClient = 'sonypictures'; // client name
var filename = "./clients/" + currentClient + "/config";
import(filename).then((ClientConfig) => {
    app.config.globalProperties.ClientConfig = ClientConfig.default;
}).catch((ClientConfig) => {
    alert('Client configuration doesnt exist! (/clients/' + currentClient + '/config.ts)');
});
```

This works fine in my development environment, but when I build it and run index.html it gives me the alert. Why isnt the imported file built along all other files?

Answer (score 0):

Using this plugin seems to solve this issue:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-dynamic-import